# Evaluation of $ \int \left(x^{3m}+x^{2m}+x^{m}\right)\cdot \left(2x^{2m}+3x^{m}+6\right)^{\frac{1}{m}}dx\;,$

Tags: calculus

> Evaluation of $\displaystyle \int \left(x^{3m}+x^{2m}+x^{m}\right)\cdot \left(2x^{2m}+3x^{m}+6\right)^{\frac{1}{m}}dx\;,$ Where $m>0$

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ Let $\displaystyle I = \int \left(x^{3m}+x^{2m}+x^{m}\right)\cdot \left(2x^{2m}+3x^{m}+6\right)^{\frac{1}{m}}dx$

Now Put $x^m=t\;,$ Then $\displaystyle mx^{m-1}dx = dt\Rightarrow dx=\frac{x}{m\cdot t}dt$

So $\displaystyle I = \frac{1}{m}\int (t^3+t^2+t)\cdot (2t^2+3t+6)^{\frac{1}{m}}\cdot \frac{1}{t}\cdot xdt$

So $\displaystyle I = \frac{1}{m}\int (t^2+t+1)\cdot (2t^2+3t+6)^{\frac{1}{m}}\cdot xdt$

Now How can I solve after that

Help me

Thanks

Comment: As $\dfrac{d(2x^{2m}+3x^m+6)}{dx}=mx^{-1}(4x^{2m}+3x^m)$
I was trying
$$x^{3m}+x^{2m}+x^m=Ax\cdot mx^{-1}(4x^{2m}+3x^m)+Bx^{m+1}mx^{-1}(4x^{2m}+3x^m)$$

Comment: The result is : $$\frac{1}{6 (m+1)} x^{m+1} \left(2 x^{2 m}+3 x^m+6\right)^{\frac{1}{m}+1}+C.$$

Comment: Try to get $x$ entirely out of your equation for $I$.

Answer (score 4):

> $$\large \mathrm {I=\int \left(x^{3m}+x^{2m}+x^{m}\right)\cdot \left(2x^{2m}+3x^{m}+6\right)^{1/m}dx}$$

---

Let $\large x=t^{1/m}$, then $\large dx=\frac1mt^{1/m-1}dt$
$$\large I=\int(t^3+t^2+t)(2t^2+3t+6)^{1/m}\frac1mt^{1/m-1}dt\\
\large =\int(t^2+t+1)(2t^3+3t^2+6t)^{1/m}\frac1mdt$$

---

Let $\large u=(2t^3+3t^2+6t)$, then $\large du=6(t^2+t+1)dt$
$$\large I=\int\frac1{6m}u^{1/m}du=\frac1{6(m+1)}u^{(m+1)/m}+C=\frac1{6(m+1)}(2t^3+3t^2+6t)^{(m+1)/m}+C'$$

---

> $$\large \mathrm{I=\frac{x^{m+1}}{6(m+1)}(2x^{2m}+3x^{m}+6)^{(m+1)/m}}+\mathcal{C}$$